# When 2 Java Lambda Functions communicate with each, do they both have to be in the same VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

When invoking AWS Java Lambda function from another AWS Java Lambda function, do they both have to be in the same VPC; if invoker function is in VPC to connect to RDS?

Comment: How is one Lambda function invoking the other Lambda function? If you're doing this via an `invoke(InvokeRequest)` API call to the Lambda service, then the networking doesn't matter. All that matters is permission to invoke the Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you configure the VPC & Subnet correctly.

Lambda Functions can run in
a) VPC owned by Lambda - accessible over Internet
b) your own VPC - accessible depending on your configuration

see also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html#vpc-internet

If you put all your Lambda Functions in **b)** your own VPC, you need to configure your VPC correctly.

If you put one Lambda Function in **a)** VPC owned by Lambda and another one in **b)** your own VPC. The Lambda Function in **b)** your own VPC needs to go over the Internet to communicate with the Lambda Function in **a)** VPC owned by Lambda. In this case you need to configure your VPC correctly.

Once you solved the network connectivity & security (SG, NACL), you need to configure the IAM.

Comment: What if I only want the invoked function to be access only by the invoking function (which is in a VPC to be able to access RDS) and nobody else?

Comment: Can Java Lambda Function B (which is invoked by Java Lambda Function A) not be in any VPC; even though Java Lambda Function A is in VPC in order to connect to RDS?

Comment: if Lambda Function B should only be invoked by Lambda Function A (which is in a VPC) and no one else...put both Lambda Functions in a VPC and lock down the access using Security Groups.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "AWS public zone" so option b) as written is unclear.

Comment: You are right. I corrected my answer and used the terminology of AWS documentation.